# HTML , Jquery Fisheye menu

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fisheye

I have used the fisheye jquery **"interface.js"** I want to make make 3rd element with 
`id="default"` should be show default like mouse over effect , Please help me thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div class="dock" id="dock1">
    <div class="dock-container2">
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#" ><span>E-Mail</span><img src="images/ui/img1.png" alt="home" width="40"/></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Contact</span><img src="images/ui/img2.png" alt="contact" width="50" /></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#" id="default"><span>Car</span><img src="images/ui/img3.png" alt="portfolio" width="60"/></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Home</span><img src="images/ui/img4.png" alt="music" width="70" /></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Air Line</span><img src="images/ui/img5.png" alt="video" width="80"  /></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Train</span><img src="images/ui/img6.png" alt="history" width="70"/></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Hotel</span><img src="images/ui/img7.png" alt="calendar" width="60"/></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Links</span><img src="images/ui/img8.png" alt="links" width="50"/></a>
        <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Call Us</span><img src="images/ui/img9.png" alt="rss" width="40" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dock1').Fisheye({
        maxWidth: 60,
        items: 'a',
        itemsText: 'span',
        container: '.dock-container2',
        itemWidth: 40,
        proximity: 80,
        alignment: 'left',
        valign: 'top',
        halign: 'center'
    });
    $("#pagecontent").slider();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$(".dock-container2:nth-child(3)").attr("id", "default")
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand.